# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable when calling a class function

Tags: python

I have a function that return a class and I save it as a object. When I try to call on a class method I'll get the error

```
location = file_type.route(env['REQUEST_URI']) # Get the location
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I have changed name on the object to make sure it is no naming collision.

On the first line I call the the method get_file_type in module route.

```
file_type = route.get_file_type(env['REQUEST_URI']) # Get File_type object
location = file_type.route(env['REQUEST_URI']) # Get the location
```

If I print out the file_type I get output `<route.File_type instance at 0x7f96e3e90950>`

I store the File_type classes in a dictionary and the method get_file_type returns a File_type based on the request.

```
path = {'html'  : File_type('html', 1, 1),
        'css'   : File_type('css', 1, 0),
        'ttf'   : File_type('ttf', 0, 0),
        }

def get_file_type(request): # return a File_type object
    extension = request.rsplit('.', 1)[-1]

    if extension in path:
        return path[extension]

    return path['html']
```

File_type class

```
class File_type:

    def __init__(self, type_, parse, route):
        self.type_ = type_
        self.parse = parse
        self.route = route

    def route(resource):
        if self.route == 1:
            for pattern, value in routes:
                if re.search(pattern, resource):
                    return value
            return None
        else:
            return resource.rsplit('.', 1)[0][1:]
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You haven't shown even which line the error is occuring on, nor even necessarily provided the code that produces the error. Read that page and edit your post accordingly.

Comment: When you initialize a `File_type`, the attribute `route` is overwriting the function `route` so you can't call it.  Give them different names

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Thanks solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

In your `File_type` class you have `route` as a method. But when you call constructor you write to `self.route` (that was a method) some integer, so you loose your method and can't call it anymore. Instead, you try to call integer. So just change the name of the method or variable `route`.

And btw. Method always has to get `self` as a parameter (your `route` method doesn't).